# Is it safe to use the NSManagedObjectID from one context to the other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have 2 NSManagedObjectContext:

1. ContextA
2. ContextB

In ContextA I managed to acquire the NSManagedObjectID of an entity. I then used this object ID to acquire the NSManagedObject in ContextB. This works fine but I want to know if this is safe. Or if you have a better and safer way to do this, let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is safe if `isTemporaryID` returns NO in ContextA. Otherwise, when the temporary object is saved, a new ID will be created and you might not find it in ContextB.

What you are doing is required if ContextA and ContextB were created on different threads and you want to access the same object in both.

Comment: It does not matter whether the contexts are created on different threads.  Each context has its own instance of the NSManagedObject.

Comment: This answer doesn't really bear on the question of whether they are thread safe.  Besides, the persistent store coordinator shared by the contexts will deal with the temporary ID issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe.  The documentation has always made it clear that you should use objectIDs across contexts.